# getInstance ошибка

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться, почему данная ошибка возникает?

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication10\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\DataController.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    LiveData<String> liveData = DataController.getInstance().getData();
                                              ^
  symbol:   method getInstance()
  location: class DataController
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        LiveData<String> liveData = DataController.getInstance().getData();

        liveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>(){


            @Override
            public void onChanged(String value) {
                textView.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

public class DataController {

    LiveData<String> liveData = DataController.getInstance().getData();
}
```

Comment: Откуда по вашему класс `DataController` должен взять метод `getInstance()`?

Comment: Я только начал изучать сохранение данных по урокам, та мне указанно, просто пример этого кода, но он не работает